# I want to add edit button next to delete button, whish would allow me to edit the value I already inserted

Tags: javascript, html, css

my friend created a to do list, you can have a look here
now I tried to create a to do list in my way, here is my code
I am almost done but I still need to add the edit icon that would allow me to edit on the inserted value once I click on it.
I appreciate that you guys help me out. sincerely.

```js
var myspan= document.getElementsByClassName("myspan");
for(var i=0; i<myspan.length;i++)
    {
     myspan[i].onClick= function()
    {
      var divit = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display="none";
    }
  }


var list =document.querySelector("ul");
list.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName==='LI')
    {
      event.target.classList.toggle('checked')
    }
});

function addBtn()
{
   var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
 if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Myul").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myinput").value="";
  
  var span = document.createElement("myspan");
  var text = document.createTextNode("\u00D7")
  span.className="myspan";
  span.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(span)
  
  for(var i=0; i<myspan.length;i++)
    {
     myspan[i].onclick = function(){
        var divit=this.parentElement;
      divit.style.display="none";
     }
    } 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align:center;
}

#mydiv:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#mydiv{
  margin-top:0;
  background: pink;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.addBtn{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #F6DDCC;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.addBtn:hover{
  background:#E59866;
  border: none;
}

#myinput{
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid none;
   width: 75%;
   height: 38px;
  float: left;
  
}
  

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #85C1E9;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-top-style: dashed;
  border-width: 0.6px;
  
}
li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: dashed;
  border-width: 0.6px;
  
}
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}
ul li.checked {
  background: #BB8FCE;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.myspan {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.myspan:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <input type="text" id="myinput" placeholder="Tittle..">
  <span class="addBtn" id="hshs" onclick="addBtn()">add</span>
</div>

<ul id="Myul">
  
</ul>
```

Comment: my friend's code : https://todolist-projects.netlify.app/      my code: https://codepen.io/yassine_hammadi/pen/NWbWdxy

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add the button and, onClick, change the li element for an input element only while the user is editing, then set it back. Here is an example of this in action. https://tareasnico.netlify.app/

Comment: ohh @josh Merrian that's a cool idea you made, but for me It's really obligatory to make the value appears in the textbox then could modify it, as it's in my friends code.

Comment: Ok so then just populate the input box with ```document.querySelector(#myinput).value = {{whatever you want}}```